# Unpacking the return value of a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function like this, which always returns exactly one record:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(pid int) RETURNS TABLE (a int, b int)
AS $$
   -- …
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I want to select rows from a table like this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , foo(p.id).*
  FROM puns AS p;
```

However, this gives a syntax error at `.*`. I couldn’t figure out how to do it with a `JOIN`, since `p.id` is an argument to the function.

How can I unpack the record returned by the function into the select query? The desired result would have three columns `id`, `a` and `b`.

I’m using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 - upgrade to postgres 9.3 and use `LATERAL`.

Option 2 - use something like:

```
SELECT sub_q.id, (sub_q.foo_row).a, (sub_q.foo_row).b
FROM (
SELECT p.id
     , foo(p.id) as foo_row
  FROM puns AS p ) sub_q;
```

Option 3 - try additional brackets like:

```
SELECT p.id
     , (foo(p.id)).*
  FROM puns AS p;
```

But I haven't tested option 3.

Comment: OPtion 3 does indeed work (at least since Postgresql 11). And why didn't I know that earlier!